# How do you read this and what is the meaning of 出家?

Tags: meaning, words

What does 出家 means? Is it to go outside the house or nun?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may be confused with the similar words 家出{いえで} and 出家｛しゅっけ｝

家出: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%AE%B6%E5%87%BA/

Definition one here says 帰らない｛かえらない｝つもりでひそかに家を出ること。「都会｛とかい｝にあこがれて家出する」「家出人」. 'Secretly leaving home with no intention of returning'. The example sentences are 'Running away from home dreaming of city life', and 'a runaway'.

出家: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%87%BA%E5%AE%B6_%28%E3%81%97%E3%82%85%E3%81%A3%E3%81%91%29/

世俗｛せぞく｝の生活｛せいかつ｝を捨て｛すて｝、僧｛そう｝となって仏道｛ぶつどう｝を修行｛しゅぎょう｝すること。また、その人｛ひと｝。
'Giving up secular life and becoming a monastic to practise Buddhism, or a person who has done this.'

In the past 家出 could mean the same thing as 出家, and it could also refer to simply leaving the house while planning to return, but neither of these meanings appear to be current judging by the example sentences. 出家 does not appear to have either of 家出's other meanings, however.